# MongoDB - get an entire document when finding a $max of some field in a collection

Tags: mongodb

So let's we have a collection of documents similar to the following ones:

```
{name : "Joe", age: 99}
{name : "Hazel", age: 23}
{name : "Alice", age: 81}
```

I can get the maximum age by aggregating with the following pipeline:

```
{$group : {$max : "$age"}}
```

however, this will only return the actual max value of `age`, whereas I'm interested in the entire document for which the field `age` is maximal. i.e, for the collection above, I'd like to get this:

```
{name : "Joe", age: 99}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest way to do this is not using `aggregate` but `findOne`.

`db.collection.findOne({}).sort({'age': -1})`

If you do want to keep using `aggregate` i would recommend sorting by age and then limiting to 1. basically doing what `findOne` does.

Any other way will require more stages.

Make sure `age` field is index'd and this query will be extremely quick.

Answer (score -1):

This can also be handle with **$project**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      age: {
        $max: "$age"
      },
      name: 1
    }
  }
])
```